# How to do String Quotes in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How do i put the variables  in this single quotes and double quotes iam confused

```
  var rdb ='<input type="radio"  id="rdb_"'+ i +' data-value1='+  labelvalue[1]  +'  data-value2='+ data[i].value +'>';
   t += '<tr><td>'+rdb+'</td><tr>';
```

Here  variable "i" is dynamic , "labelvalue[1] " is dynamic   and "data[i].value " is dynamic 
Due to this iam not able to produce the Dynamic Radio buttons  .  So the View source looks in this way

How do i correctly produce this using single quotes and double  quotes 
     input type="radio" id ="rdbacc_0"  data-value1="testRYSTAYTYTAST"  data-value="007"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most part, you were fine — just missing an end-double-quote after the `id` value and quotes around your `data-value`s:

```
var rdb ='<input type="radio"  id="rdb_'+ i +'" data-value1="'+  labelvalue[1]  + '" data-value2="'+ data[i].value +'">';
t += '<tr><td>'+rdb+'</td><tr>';
```

The best thing to do is to pick a consistent choice of which quote you'll use (which you did), in this case double quotes for the actual markup and single quotes to delimit the code, and then start with what you want to end up with and make sure the quotes are correct, so for instance:

```
var rdb ='<input type="radio"  id="rdb_{i}" data-value1="{dv1}" data-value2="{dv2}">';
t += '<tr><td>'+rdb+'</td><tr>';
```

Then go back and add `' + x + '` in place of the bits in curly brackets. (You don't have to use curly brackets, that's just an example.)

You may also find the new [jQuery templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) plug-in useful for this stuff.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using jQuery this would probably function and read much better:

```
$('<input />', {
    'id':'rdb_'+i,
    'type':'radio',
    'data-value1':labelvalue[1],
    'data-value2':data[i].value
}).appendTo('<tr><td></td></td>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to replace such "constructs" with an `Array`. That has a better readability and in most cases is **faster** than string concat by `+`.

```
var rdb = [
    '<input type="radio"  id="rdb_"',
    i,
    '"data-value1="',
    labelvalue[1],
    '"data-value2="'
    data[i].value,
    '>'
];

rdb.join('');
```

Comment: @Someone: this answer was just a suggestion for better readability. Please select T.J. Crowder's answer as correct, since he really answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

you seem to be almost there, some of your quotes are in the wrong place

```
 var rdb ='<input type="radio"  id="rdb_'+ i +'" data-value1="'+  labelvalue[1]  +'"  data-value2="'+ data[i].value +'">';
   t += '<tr><td>'+rdb+'</td><tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do it ..

```
var rdb ='<input type="radio"  id="rdb_'+ i +'" data-value1="'+  labelvalue[1]  +'" data-value2="'+ data[i].value +'">';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var rdb ='<input type="radio"  id="rdb_'+ i +'" data-value1="' +  labelvalue[1]  +'"  data-value2="'+ data[i].value + '">';

t += '<tr><td>' + rdb + ' </td><tr>';
```

should do it

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, here's some thinking outside the box. Don't put yourself in such a difficult to read situation. Use .attr().

Answer (score 0):

you can use the helo variable in you string

var helo = "'"+ ok +"'";

OR

use this directly in your string

""" + color + """;